# how I can get array based on another array position ? in android

Tags: android, arrays, string, int

I want to get an array based on another array click position like :

```
String[] nissanArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nissan);
String name = nissanArray[pos];
int nameInt = Integer.parseInt("R.array." + name);
targetArray = getResources().getStringArray(nameInt);
```

and I got an error when using this : I believe the error starts from Line int ....

Comment: At runtime ("R.array." + name) will form a string not an integer. Each resource is assigned a int id during creation of apk package.

Comment: Why are u doing like this you can get string directly ?

Comment: so I can not use this method!? , and I have to switch cases for more than 35 array !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getIdentifier` method of class `android.content.res.Resources`. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for the details.

It allows you to convert a resource name to the integer resource id.

Answer (score 0):

do you know what you are trying to do ?? first understand your code

getStringArray(R.array.nissan);
in that integer parameter we should pass

that you are trying to pass integer using convert string into int is totally wrong

it required integer which mentioned in R.java file and it cant retrieved it by your syntax

when you write (R.Array.nissan)
then it linked R.java file and return integer for that from file